# ngForm zero value in custom input number picker

Tags: angular, input, numbers, picker

I have a problem

- On server side PHP, api returns json where some items have zero values.
  I use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK on PHP side.
- On angular side:

```
<app-number-picker name="scoreEq1" [(ngModel)]="match.scoreEq1" #score="ngModel"></app-number-picker>
```

Then, I have customize an number picker component:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3 input-md">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text decrease" (click)="decrease();">-</span></div>
  <input [name]="name" [(ngModel)]="value" class="form-control counter" type="number" step="1">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text increase" (click)="increase();" style="border-left: 0px;">+</span></div>
</div>
```

My code is inspired from [blog.thoughtram.io](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html)
In component ts:

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-number-picker',
  templateUrl: './numberPicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./numberPicker.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumberPickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class NumberPickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input()
  name: string;
  @Input() val: number;
  // Both onChange and onTouched are functions
  onChange: any = () => { };
  onTouched: any = () => { };

  get value() {
    return this.val;
  }

  set value(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.onChange(val);
    this.onTouched();
  }
  // We implement this method to keep a reference to the onChange
  // callback function passed by the forms API
  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  // We implement this method to keep a reference to the onTouched
  // callback function passed by the forms API
  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  // This is a basic setter that the forms API is going to use
  writeValue(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  decrease() {
    if (this.value === 0 || this.value === null) {
      this.value = null;
    } else {
      this.value--;
    }
  }

  increase() {
    if (isNaN(this.value) || this.value === null) {
      this.value = 0;
    } else {
      this.value++;
    }
  }

}
```

- My problem is when match.scoreEq1 = 0 => This value is NOT displayed in my input => it keeps blank !
  It seems "undefined" when there is zero value.

NB: match.scoreEq1 can be null => I want to display blank in that case

Where is the problem ? ngModel ? ControlValueAccessor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is because in your `writeValue(value)` method you check `if(value)`,
but if your value is 0 this actually evaluates to false and the value of your component is never set. Just replace the if statement as follows:

```
writeValue(value) {
   if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
     this.value = value;
   }
}
```